# Prove that the following is a Function (piecewise defined)

Tags: analysis, functions, proof-writing

Let $f: \mathbb{N} \mapsto \mathbb{N}$ be defined as:

$f(x) = \begin{cases}
       x+1, &\quad\text{if } x<16, \text{ $x$ is even}\\
       x-16, &\quad\text{if } x\geq16 \text{ $x$ is even} \\
       x+16, &\quad\text{if } x \text{ is odd} 
     \end{cases}$

I can **see** that for any valid $x$ this is a function, but how do I prove something like that?
Any help/hints appreciated.

Comment: Show that for all $x$, there is exactly one $y\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $f(x)=y$.

Comment: @79037662, yea thats what I am thinking and I can see that thats the case, I just dont know I can construct i.e start **proving** it

Comment: let $y_1$ and $y_2$ be such $f(x) = y_1$ and $f(x) = y_2$, then prove that $y_1 = y_2$